# How can I get an ArrayList from an ArrayList sorted by id

Tags: java, android, for-loop, kotlin

I have mList2 with values. There are values with the same id. How can I get a List or ArrayList in which objects with the same id are grouped and add it to mLists?

```
mList = ArrayList<DataPost>()
            mLists = ArrayList<ArrayList<DataPost>>()
            var f= mList2[0].ids_post
            for ((b,o) in mList2.withIndex()){
                if (o.ids_post.equals(f)){
                    mList.add(o)
                }else{
                    mLists.addAll(listOf(mList))
                    mList.clear()
                    mList.add(o)
                    f = o.ids_post
                }
            }
```

Comment: To make this clearer, can you give us an example of the data before and after?

Comment: Do you need a `groupBy` operation? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html

Comment: @Neo No, I did this in a database query

Comment: @YakovShaikevich kotlin `groupBy` is completely different from sql `Group By` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the program meeting your requirements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arrId[] = { "India", "England", "France", "China", "India", "France", "India", "England", "Germany" };
        List<String> mList2 = Arrays.asList(arrId);
        List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<String> itemsAlreadyGrouped = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mList2.size(); i++) {
            List<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
            boolean groupCandidateFound = false;
            if (!itemsAlreadyGrouped.contains(mList2.get(i))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mList2.size(); j++) {
                    if (mList2.get(i).equals(mList2.get(j))) {
                        groupList.add(mList2.get(i));
                        groupCandidateFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (groupCandidateFound) {
                    itemsAlreadyGrouped.add(mList2.get(i));
                }
            }
            if (groupList.size() > 0) {             
                output.add(groupList);
            }
        }

        //Let's test the logic
        for (List<String> group : output) {
            System.out.println(group);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output for the given sample of items:**

```
[India, India, India]
[England, England]
[France, France]
[China]
[Germany]
```

Comment: And like for example:  `data class DataPost(var text:String? = null, var photo:String? = null,
                         var type:String = "",
                         var ids_post:String = "", var position:String? = null)`    How can I sort by ids _post?